# How can I configure Microsoft Teams so that my recordings can, by default, be downloaded by the other meeting attendees?

Tags: windows, microsoft-teams

How can I configure Microsoft Teams so that my recordings can, by default, be downloaded by the other meeting attendees? By default, recordings are view-only, which is inconvenient for other meeting attendees as well as the recording owner.

I use Microsoft Teams on Microsoft Windows.

[image]

Comment: You might find an answer at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, one cannot configure Microsoft Teams so that recordings are, by default, be downloaded by the other meeting attendees. One must change the permission for each recording.